# Как переделать код так, чтобы в нем был функциональный интерфейс?

Tags: java, lambda

Я знаю, что функциональный интерфейс – это интерфейс, который содержит только 1 абстрактный метод, но не могу понять, как сделать так, чтобы он был в моем коде. Всего у меня четыре класса.
Первый класс Car:

```
package laba;
import java.util.Comparator;

abstract public class Car{

    private String company;
    private String name;
    private int year;
    private boolean hasICE;

    public Car() {
    }

    public Car(String company, boolean hasICE) {
        this.setCompany(company);
        this.setHasICE(hasICE);
    }

    public Car(String company, String name, int year, boolean hasICE) {
        this.setCompany(company);
        this.setName(name);
        this.setYear(year);
        this.setHasICE(hasICE);
    }

    public String getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public Boolean getHasICE() {
        return isHasICE();
    }

    public abstract boolean equal(Car car);

    public abstract String toString();

    public abstract Car changeNameAndYear(String newName, int newYear);

    private void setCompany(String company) {
        this.company = company;
    }

    private void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    private boolean isHasICE() {
        return hasICE;
    }

    private void setHasICE(boolean hasICE) {
        this.hasICE = hasICE;
    }

}
```

Второй класс ElectricCar:

```
package laba;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class ElectricCar extends Car {

    public ElectricCar(String company) {
        super(company, false);
    }

    public ElectricCar(String company, String name, int year) {
        super(company, name, year, false);
    }

    public ElectricCar() {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean equal(Car car) {
        if (car.getHasICE()) {
            return false;
        }

        return (super.getCompany().equals(car.getCompany()) && super.getName().equals(car.getName()) && super.getYear() == car.getYear()) ? true : false;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Company - " + super.getCompany() + ", Name - " + super.getName() + ", Year - " + super.getYear() + ", electric car";
    }

    @Override
    public Car changeNameAndYear(String newName, int newYear) {
        return new ElectricCar(super.getCompany(), newName, newYear);
    }


}
```

Третий класс ICE_Car:

```
package laba;

    public class ICE_Car extends Car {

        public ICE_Car(String company){
            super(company, true);
        }

        public ICE_Car(String company, String name, int year){
            super(company, name, year, true);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equal(Car car) {
            if(!car.getHasICE()) 
                return false;

            return (super.getCompany().equals(car.getCompany()) && super.getName().equals(car.getName()) && super.getYear() == car.getYear())? true : false;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Company - " + super.getCompany() + ", Name - " + super.getName() + ", Year - " + super.getYear() + ", car with ICE";
        }

        @Override
        public Car changeNameAndYear(String newName, int newYear) {
            return new ICE_Car(super.getCompany(), newName, newYear);
        }

    }
```

Четвертый класс Main:

```
package laba;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import static java.util.Comparator.*;

public class Main {

    public static <T> Comparator<T> nullsFirst(Comparator<T> comparator) {
        return (a, b) -> {
            if (a == null) {
                return (b == null) ? 0 : -1;
            }

            if (b == null) {
                return 1;
            }

            // a and b are not null here
            return comparator.compare(a, b);
        };
    }

    public static <T> Comparator<T> nullsLat(Comparator<T> comparator) {
        return (a, b) -> {
            if (a == null) {
                return (b == null) ? 0 : 1;
            }

            if (b == null) {
                return -1;
            }

            // a and b are not null here
            return comparator.compare(a, b);
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Car> list = new ArrayList();

        list.add(new ICE_Car("Bugatti","La Voiture Noire",2019));
        list.add(new ElectricCar("Tesla","X P100D", 2017));
        list.add(new ICE_Car("Hyundai","Grand i10 X", 2015));
        list.add(new ICE_Car("Audi","Typ R Imperator", 1927));
        list.add(new ElectricCar("BMW","i3", 2018));



        System.out.println("Начальный список машин: \n");
        list.forEach((l) -> System.out.println(String.format("%8s, %d, %s", l.getName(), l.getYear(), l.getCompany())));
        System.out.println("______________________");

        Comparator<Car> nameComparator = (car1, car2) -> car1.getName().compareTo(car2.getName());
        list.sort(nameComparator);
        System.out.println("Сортировка по имени: \n");
        list.forEach((l) -> System.out.println(String.format("%8s, %d, %s", l.getName(), l.getYear(), l.getCompany())));
        System.out.println("___________________________________");

        // если надо перемешивать - то Collections.shuffle(list);

        Comparator<Car> nameComparatorDesc = nameComparator.reversed();
        list.sort(nameComparatorDesc);
        System.out.println("Сортировка по обратному имени: \n");
        list.forEach((l) -> System.out.println(String.format("%8s, %d, %s", l.getName(), l.getYear(), l.getCompany())));
        System.out.println("____________________________________");

        // сравниваем по имени, если если есть одинаковые - по компании
        Comparator<Car> nameAndCompany = Comparator.comparing(Car::getName).thenComparing(Car::getCompany);
        list.sort(nameAndCompany);
        System.out.println("Сортировка по имени и компании: \n");
        list.forEach((l) -> System.out.println(String.format("%8s, %d, %s", l.getName(), l.getYear(), l.getCompany())));

        // добавим пустой объект
        list.add(null);
        // сортируем по имение пусты сначала
        list.sort(nullsFirst(nameComparator));
        System.out.println("_____________________________________");
        System.out.println("Сортировка по первому пустому имени: \n");
        list.forEach((l) -> {if (l!=null) 
                  System.out.println(String.format("%8s, %d, %s", l.getName(),  l.getYear(), l.getCompany()));
                          else System.out.println(l);}
        );

        // сортируем по имение пусты в конце
        list.sort(nullsLast(nameComparator));
        System.out.println("_____________________________________");
        System.out.println("Сортировка по последнему пустому имени: \n");
        list.forEach((l) -> {if (l!=null) 
                  System.out.println(String.format("%8s, %d, %s", l.getName(),  l.getYear(), l.getCompany()));
                          else System.out.println(l);}
        );

        // запишем в TreeSet и отсортируем по имени и компании, пустые первые
        System.out.println("______________________________________________");
        System.out.println("TreeSet sort по имени и Company NULL FIRST: \n");

        TreeSet tree = new TreeSet(nullsFirst(nameAndCompany));
        list.forEach((l) ->tree.add(l));
        tree.forEach(System.out::println);

    }
}
```

Comment: Для начала определитесь, что вы хотите, чтобы у вас там было

Comment: А еще у вас `equals` неправильный - у вас там стоит `@Override`, но метод называется не `equals`, а `equal`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не уверен, что вам в коде нужен функциональный интерфейс. Они в основном используются в нескольких случаях:

1. В качестве параметра для принимающего значения в методе. В таком случае в метод обычно передается лямбда. Пример - [`Stream#map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-):

   `<R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T,? extends R> mapper)`
2. В качестве типа для написания собственной функции(обычно - лямбды). Пример(без лямбды):

   `CompositionFunction<Double, Double> doubleNumber = 
           new CompositionFunction<Double, Double>() {
              public Double call(Double x) {
                return 2*x;
              }
           };`

   Пример с лямбдой: `Function<Double, Double> doubleFunction = x -> 2 * x;`
3. В качестве шаблона для функции(обычно - лямбды) - если не подходят интерфейсы `Function`, `Predicate`, `Consumer`, `Supplier` и остальные:

   `@FunctionalInterface
   public interface PalindromeChecker {
    boolean isPalidrome(String s);
   }`

   Потом вы можете применить этот интерфейс к п.1 или п.2 выше. Функция должна будет принимать строку и возвращать `boolean` значение.

Это основные способы использования функциональных интерфейсов в коде. У вас я не вижу, где надо это применять.

---

Вот еще пример использования функционального интерфейса(в данном случае - [`Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html)). Есть 2 класса: `Salesman`(продавец) и `Customer`(покупатель).

```
public class Customer {
 private String emailAddress;

 public Customer(String emailAddress) {
  this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
 }

 public String getEmailAddress() {
  return emailAddress;
 }
}
```

---

```
public class Salesman {
 private Customer bestCustomer;

 Salesman(Customer bestCustomer) {
  this.bestCustomer = bestCustomer;
 }

 public Customer getBestCustomer() {
  return bestCustomer;
 }
}
```

---

У `Salesman` есть поле `Customer`. А у `Customer` есть поле `emailAdress`.

Теперь, вы можете вот так присвоить емаил покупателю:

```
Customer customer = new Customer("bestcustomer@thebestcustomer.com");
Salesman salesman = new Salesman(customer);
//возвратит емаил покупателя
System.out.println(salesman.getBestCustomer().getEmailAddress());
```

---

Но, у этого подхода нет гибкости функционального решения. Напишем функциональное решение. Начнем с трех выражений:

• `customerToEmailAddress`: возвращает емаил, находящийся в `Customer`

• `salesmanToBestCustomer`: возвращает объект `Customer`, находящийся в `Salesman`

• `toEmailAddress`: составная функция, которая возвращает емаил лучшего покупателя

Вот эти три функции:

```
Function<Customer, String> customerToEmailAddress = Customer::getEmailAddress;

Function<Salesman, Customer> salesmanToBestCustomer = Salesman::getBestCustomer;

Function<Salesman, String> toEmailAddress = salesmanToBestCustomer.andThen(customerToEmailAddress);
```

Теперь, можно сделать так: `System.out.println(toEmailAddress.apply(salesman));`

Comment: а где эти 3 функции надо прописывать? в 3 разных интерфейсах? @Anton Sorokin

Comment: @Dred Не, функции и интерфейсы тут не причем. Вот у вас есть интерфейс - `Functional`, и вы на его основе можете сделать 3 функции - 3 метода из интерфейса `Functional`. Пример 1ой функции - это метод(`apply`) который принимает лямбду(в данном случае `Customer::getEmailAddress`) и применяют его к значению(в данном случае `Customer`), а потом возвращают `String`. Объявить вы их можете где угодно(точнее, там, где вы можете создавать экземпляры классов). И применять где угодно. По сути, вы там создаете отложенное действие, и потом можете его где хотите применить.

Comment: то есть, из вашего примера, после `new Customer("bestcustomer@thebestcustomer.com")`  я должен написать `Function<Customer, String> customerToEmailAddress = Customer::getEmailAddress;` и тогда уже внутри `Salesman` можно использовать эту функцию? Я просто не пойму тот случай, когда для `Customer` мы еще не заполнили конструктор, но пытаемся вызывать функцию `customerToEmailAddress`. Как Java узнает какой email присвоен покупателю?

Comment: @Dred Ну, там идет просто доступ к экземпляру Customer, а потом к переменной email. Если вы не инициализируете переменную, то будет NPE(впрочем, как и если бы вы где то в коде написали `Customer.getEmail()`)

Comment: то есть в вашем классе должно быть так `private String emailAddress="myemail@something"` ?

Comment: @Dred ну, во первых выше в коде я уже инициализировал переменные, во вторых я по умолчанию предполагаю что они не пустые